# what is the reason of a Short Circuit?

Tags: short-circuit

I am new to electronics, and I don't understand the theory of a `Short Circuit`.

**Why does a Short Circuit happen?**

Comment: Please google around first and do some reading, then come back and ask us specifically what it is about the theory that you do not understand.

Comment: I would start with V=IR and output impedance or resistance of a source/battery.

Comment: Fumble-fingers holding screwdrivers.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "theory of a short circuit".

A short circuit is usually just an unwanted connection between two points in a circuit.  A short circuit may be caused by the insulation on wires wearing away as the wires rub on each other.  On a circuit board, a short may be caused by a blob of solder in the wrong place.

Sometimes, we intentionally "short" things while doing tests on a circuit.  For example, if we think that a switch may be faulty, we may place a short (a temporary connection) between its terminals to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: ...I saw once a repairman repairing a flipper. The main fuse (perhaps 10A) kept to blow. He took his pliers and put a short-circuit across the blown fuse, saying "these pliers are more than 10A". Infact, a coil in the flipper blew up with smoke etc etc. He replaced the coil and the repair was done.